# can i identify a link that have an imag with certain href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a web application, and i need to adjust a People Picker dialog height. currently to keep firing the script when the user open/close the dialog , i set a timer (2 seconds for the script to run), as follow:-

```
var interval = null; //Defines the start interval variable

$(document).ready(function () { // jQuery needed for this
    /* People Picker Fix Starts */
    if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 10") > -1) { // IE 10 Specific condition for People Picker Bug
       interval = setInterval(adjustPeoplePicker, 2000);
    }
    /* People Picker Fix Ends */
});

function adjustPeoplePicker() {
    if ($('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#resultcontent').length > 0) {
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#resultcontent').css('height', '350px');
        $('.ms-dlgFrame').contents().find('#MetadataTreeControlTreeSearch').css('height', '350px');
       //clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

here is the realted markup for the dialog to open:-

```
<a id="ctl00_ctl41_g_a4fb58d0_ad0d_40cf_a4a3_ccabea410e43_ff141_ctl00_ctl00_UserField_browse" href="javascript:" onclick="__Dialog__ctl00_ctl41_g_a4fb58d0_ad0d_40cf_a4a3_ccabea410e43_ff141_ctl00_ctl00_UserField(); return false;" title="Browse">
<img alt="Browse" src="/_layouts/15/images/addressbook.gif" title="Browse">
</a>
```

so my question if i can fire the script only when the user click on `<a>` that have an `<imag>` inside it where the imag `src =  addressbook.gif` , instead of keeps firing the script every 2 seconds??

Comment: Yes you can. You just have to change your code.

Comment: so can you adivce more on this please? how to modify the selector ?

Comment: Remove the interval function and add an onclick handler that checks if the `a`nchor tag has an image with the specified source in it. Have you made an effort to try it?

Comment: @john G: What solution did you come up with in the end or do you still need any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a img').on('click', callScriptForImage);

....
// it is executed every time, but will call function adjustPeoplePicker()
// only if src attribute includes addressbook.gif, as you asked
function callScriptForImage(e){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  // read image src attribute
  if( /addressbook\.gif/.test(src)){
    // if src attribute includes addressbook.gif, call function
    adjustPeoplePicker();
  }
}
```

You could also listen for clicks on image that have that `src` attribute, with:

```
$('a img[src$="addressbook.gif"]').on('click', adjustPeoplePicker);
```

This way it is a lot cleaner.

Comment: but in this case the callScriptForImage function is going to be called whenever users click  on any link that have any imag,, could i control this more?

Comment: Yes, this will call whenever ANY image is clicked, but that's what you're asking for.

As you posed the question, you're asking for the code to check and execute code any time an image is clicked that has "addressbook.gif" as the src. Is this not the case?

Comment: Well, actually the question asks to fire the script on clicks on a tags which contain an img tag with a mentioned src part. Here the click is set on an img tag which could - yet might not - lead to an unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're asking to check to see whether the `<img>` **`src`** = addressbook.gif and NOT the `href` of `<a>`?

If that is the case, this should work for you:

```
$('a img').on('click', function () {
    //Check to see if if the href matches addressbook.gif
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var regex = /addressbook\.gif/i;
    if (regex.test(src)) {
        // Execute your code here.
    } else {
        //Put anything else you want here
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

JRad The Bad

Comment: yes u are correct i mean src not href (i updated my question). but inside ur script the function will be called whenever users clicks on any link that have imag,, so could i control this ?

Comment: As posted above, you're asking to check the href of the image.
The only way to get around this is to instead use an `id` attribute and simply attach the jQuery to that id.

I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: ok but your wrote src == 'addressbook.gif' but the source will not be exactly addressbook.gif it will end with this ,, not exact match is this correct ?

Comment: That depends. If you are using a static page and the path to the image is in the same directory, then `src` will be "addressbook.gif". If instead you're using a path pulled from another function or variable, I'd reference that like this: `if(src == pathURL)`

Comment: You can not use `id`, what if he needs more than 1 image, to check on

Comment: @JRadtheBad no from the markup you can see that the src is /"_layouts/15/images/addressbook.gif" ,,

Comment: @Nermin the problem is that the link will have different id on different forms not just single id,, so that why i need to do a workaround selection,, did u get my point ?

Comment: @johnG: How many of these images are there? There's not going to be a heavy load on the system running this short of a script on every image. jQuery is a client side language so there's no issues with server load on this. Code only executes if the `img` has the right source. I'll update the solution to reflect the proper pathing.

Comment: @Nermin: Both our solutions require a click action so he can't check multiple elements at the same time like this anyways. The jQuery listener event on the edit in my solution would work for ANY element that has 'address-book' as the `id` no matter how many elements have that `id`. `id` isn't a unique identifier in HTML.

Comment: @johnG: You **can** have multiple ID's for each element in HTML (just like with classes), so you don't have to worry about conflicting `id`s. The `id` solution will still work and is honestly probably your best solution.
Without seeing more of the project, we can't really see what any other requirements are, where the image is coming from, conflicting scopes, etc...

If you want more exact help, you'll need to provide more exact information.

Comment: No, the solution would not work with multiple same id anchors: https://jsfiddle.net/5v1926bg/1/

Comment: Hmmm... Seems your are correct. The event listener only is attached to the first instance of the `id`. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function setClick(){
                var tL = document.querySelectorAll("img[src*='addressbook.gif']"); //Getting all images which src contains addressbook.gif
                for(var i=0, j=tL.length;i<j; i++){
                    //Just to visualize
                    tL[i].style.outline = '1px solid red';

                    //We actually click on the parent (a) and not the img so we set the click on the a tag
                    //The other tags will keep your normal onclick settings.
                    tL[i].parentNode.onclick = function(){
                        //Put your special script for those cases.
                        //adjustPeoplePicker() //Some version of this.
                        return false
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload = 'setClick()'>
        <a href = 'https://www.google.com'><img alt = 'Browse' src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png' /></a>
        <a href = 'https://www.google.com'><img alt = 'Browse' src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png?test=addressbook.gif' /></a>
        <a href = 'https://www.google.com'><img alt = 'Browse' src = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png' /></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7u3m2cng/1/

Comment: Good solution. `querySelectorAll()` prevents the code execution everytime an image is clicked so this is probably what he'll be looking for as a solution.